# convert a video to a sequence of frame images

Tags: gstreamer, video-processing

I need to capture a video using a webcam and output a single image for each video frame captured.

I have tried using gstreamer with a multifilesink, e.g.:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! pngenc ! multifilesink location="frame%d.png"
```

However, this does not actually output every frame, meaning that if I record for 2 seconds at 30 fps, I don't get 60 images. I'm assuming this is because the encoding can't go that fast, so I need another method.

I figured it might work if I have one pipeline capture a video, and a separate pipeline convert that video to frames, but I don't know enough about codecs. Do I need to encode the video to a file like h264 or mp4 just to then decode it again?

Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions? Keep in mind that I need to be able to do this in code, not using an application like Adobe Premiere, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could simply add a queue in there like this:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! pngenc ! multifilesink location="frame%d.png"
```

This should make sure the video-capture is allowed to run at 30 fps, and then writing it to
disk can happen in its own tempo. Just be aware that the queue will grow to quite a large size
if you leave this setup for too long.

Answer (score 1):

the solution I have to offer doesn't use gstreamer but ffmpeg. I hope that's fine for you too.

As described in [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042249), you can use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi frame%d.png
```

to get a png/jpg image for each frame of the video.
But depending on the input file you use, you might have to convert it to an MPEG vid before running ffmpeg.

Note:
If you want leading zeroes in your image file names, use `%05d` instead (for 5-digit numbers, like in C's `printf()`):

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi frame%05d.png
```

The output file format depends on the file extension, so you might use `.jpg`, `.bmp`, ... instead of `.png`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this in two parts.

Write video to file.

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! xvidenc ! queue ! avimux ! filesink location=test.avi
```

Post process.

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 filesrc location=test.avi ! decodebin ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! pngenc ! multifilesink location="frame%d.png"
```

Comment: Is that a typo or did you use gst-launch (0.x) for the first command and gst-launch-1.0 for the second?